# show recent data in data grid view

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on windows application.

In that application, I am saving data in database.

And retrieving data in data grid view.

For that I am using following code :

```
var expenselist = db.SP_TodaysExpense().Where(a => a.Date <= DateTime.Now.Date).ToList();

DgvTodaysExpense.DataSource = expenselist;
```

above code shows all the data in database. But, I want to show data that are added only after opening the application.

So how can I do this ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Save the current date and time when you open that application and use it replacing the actual DateTime.Now.Date

Comment: I will try..Thanks @Steve

Comment: `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartTime` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save a Datetime Value in the App Settings (Right click Project => Propeties => Settings ):

**Note : Use Scope => User in order to be able to update the value.**

Then in Program.cs Main method add:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.LastOpenedTime = DateTime.Now;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

and change your query to:

```
DateTime queryTime = Properties.Settings.Default.LastOpenedTime ;
var expenselist = db.SP_TodaysExpense().Where(a => a.Date >= queryTime ).ToList();

DgvTodaysExpense.DataSource = expenselist;
```

For More on App Settings : Read [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: Here, querytime shows "01-01-0001 00:00:00" and my query returns nothing.

Comment: @sweets It can't be `01-01-0001 00:00:00` if you set it in `Program.cs` to DateTime.Now;

Comment: While using settings is a really good thing to know for some cases, but here using settings is really pointless, because we don't need to store it for the next time the application run. Read also my answer here, probably it has something new, better than using settings.

Answer (score 2):

> **OP:** I want to show data that are added only after opening the application.

Based on your requirement, you need to get start time of your application.  Storing start time in settings is pointless (while it will work). There are also better options:

- **Option 1 -** Get start up time of the application using [`StartTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.starttime(v=vs.110).aspx) of [Current Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getcurrentprocess(v=vs.110).aspx):

  ```
  var start = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartTime;
  ```
- **Option 2 -**  Store StartTime in a static property of `Program` class:

  ```
  public static DateTime StartTime { get; private set; } /* Usage: Program.StartTime */
  [STAThread]
  static void Main()
  {
      StartTime = DateTime.Now; 
      //...
  }
  ```